# Fix Resharper intellisense

Tags: resharper

Does anyone know how to fix this, besides pressing esc then typing the variable name again?

[image]

```
JetBrains ReSharper 6.1 C# Edition
Build 6.1.37.86 on 2011-12-21T04:15:24
Plugins: none
Visual Studio 10.0.30319.1.
```

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You may want to try changing the IntelliSense option:

[image: Resharper Visual Studio Options]

Whether you're using IntelliSense ReSharper or Visual Studio, try changing it, then changing it back. I've sometimes had similar issues and toggling the option can help.

Comment: This still solution still works when faced with the issue in Visual Studio 2015 and ReSharper 2017.3

Comment: This solution still works in Visual Studio 2017 and ReSharper 2019.1.

Comment: Not working for me on VS2022 17.7.6, Resharper 2023.2.20231101.135622. Going to switch to VS Intellisense for now.

Answer (score 2):

Usually restart of Visual Studio tends to re-enable intellisense, I'd much rather a proper fix from JetBrains.

Answer (score 0):

For me, R# intellisense stopped working after installing (and then uninstalling) certain R# extensions. Adding the extensions back fixed the problem.

**Edit 1:**

Also, try playing with the R# IntelliSense options and see what happens.

In particular switch "Options | Environment | IntelliSense | Completion Appearance | Display completion items in:" from "Visual Studio IntelliSense font" to "Text Editor font" and back.

In the end I tried many things (including upgrading and downgrading R#) over and over again until R# IntelliSense was back.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and I hadn't realized I had opened a project in Folder view mode. Resharper Intellisense won't show unless you switch to a solution view.

Make sure you select a solution instead of a Folder view:
[image: Visual Studio Solution Explorer, with Switch Views popup showing]